# Solid objects in spherical coordinate system like shapes in polar one

Tags: spherical-coordinates

When you have polar coordinate system you can generate plots like Rose or spiral

[image]

Is something like this possible in spherical coordinate system. Where you shave solid object like this (I was thinking about a mesh with lines or smooth with lighting). Do you examples of images, maybe a book that show this or mathematical equations to generate them? Or maybe you know some easy way to visualize this? I may write some program that generate those (so I can play with this) but it will take long time to finish, when I will be able to see how this look like. And I don't even know if I will succeed in creating such program.

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#/media/File:Spherical_Harmonics.png), for example, is taken from the Wikipedia page on spherical harmonics.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thanks there is also wikipedia page for this "[Spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics)"

Comment: You're welcome. I don't really know how they plotted those solid roses, it surely involves polar coordinates. They look beautiful.